# Force Binding Update Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

How can I force my objects DataContext bindings to update? I'm using an event on a grid, and binding updates are not being processed before my event fires.

Any cheap tricks to get around this?
In the end I can always do things the old manual way of getting the values from my textboxes and updating my object, but it'd be nice to have binding do it for me.

**UPDATE**

My grid contains two textboxes. If a user clicks on the grid (MouseButtonUp event) then I save the changes. But in my MouseButtonUp event handler, the datacontext is not up to date yet. I'd imagine it's because a text box only updates when focus is lost.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can force an update of the source a binding by calling the UpdateSource() methond on on the binding. Try adding it to the MouseButtonUp event handler just before saving.

Like so:

```
BindingExpression binding = FirstTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty)
if (null != binding) binding.UpdateSource();
```

You can find more information about this on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.updatesource(VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Alternativly you can catch TextInput event (it will fire when user presses enter inside text box)
and then change focus to second textBox. loosing focus will update binded value.